# Javascript : where are high level data structures?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I'm writing a client program for a game in Javascript but I'm new in Javascript world. Core Javascript lack of high level data structures.

I've found code snippets on internet but I'm looking for a reference library (like commons-collection or google-collection in java world).

I found this post: [JavaScript implementation of a set data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523436/javascript-implementation-of-a-set-data-structure) which refers to jshashtable and closure.

Are they reference implementations? Do you know something else?

Thanks

Comment: Google closure library has `goog.structs.*` - http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/#svn/trunk/closure/goog/structs

Answer (score 3):

http://www.datajett.com/Tuts/JScriptGen/javascriptDataStructs.pdf

http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html

http://www.learningapi.com/blog/archives/000078.html

Answer (score 0):

http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/ gives you everything Ruby has, which is a lot.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/js-sdsl/js-sdsl

A javascript standard data structure library which benchmark against C++ STL.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33367605)