# Set of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, data-structures, set

I'd like to have a set of objects in Javascript.  That is, a data structure that contains only unique objects.

Normally using properties is recommended, e.g. `myset["key"] = true`.  However, I need the keys to be objects.  I've read that Javascript casts property names to strings, so I guess I can't use `myset[myobject] = true`.

I could use an array, but I need something better than O(n) performance for adding, finding and removing items.

It needs to be able to tell objects apart by reference only, so given:

```
var a = {};
var b = {};
```

then both `a` and `b` should be able to be added, because they're separate objects.

Basically, I'm after something like C++'s `std::set`, that can store Javascript objects.  Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript implementation of a set data structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523436/javascript-implementation-of-a-set-data-structure)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

ES6 provides a native [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
let s = new Set();
let a = {};
let b = {};

s.add(a);

console.log(s.has(a));  // true
console.log(s.has(b));  // false
```

Comment: `new Set([{one: "one"}, {one: "one"}]).size` is 2. Shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: @ndtreviv: No, they’re not the same object. `{one: "one"} !== {one: "one"}`

Comment: You're right. I ended up using lodash's _.uniqWith and _.isEqual to get unique Objects.

Comment: Thank you @ndtreviv! I used `uniqueObjects = _.uniqWith(objects, _.isEqual)`

Answer (score 24):

Here's a mad suggestion ... key it on the result of `JSON.stringify(object)`

Comment: This is what I keep thinking of, but I really really don't want to do things this way :/

Comment: TypeError: cyclic object value

Comment: Will give false negative results when order of properties in object is different.

Answer (score 11):

I'm answering my own question, but I came up with an alternative solution I thought was interesting and thought it would be useful to share it.

cwolves' answer gave me an idea.  Providing an object's `toString()` method uniquely identifies the instance, properties of an object can be used to store a set of objects.  Essentially, to store object `x`, you can use `items[x.toString()] = x;`.  Note that the value is the object itself, so then the set of objects can be extracted by looking at all `item`'s properties and dumping all the values in to an array.

Here's the class, which I call `ObjectSet`, in full.  It requires objects are uniquely identified by their `toString()` method, which is OK for my purposes.  `add`, `remove` and `contains` should all run in better than O(n) time - whatever javascript's property access efficiency is, which hopefully is either O(1) or O(n log n).

```
// Set of objects.  Requires a .toString() overload to distinguish objects.
var ObjectSet = function ()
{
    this.items = {};
    this.item_count = 0;
};

ObjectSet.prototype.contains = function (x)
{
    return this.items.hasOwnProperty(x.toString());
};

ObjectSet.prototype.add = function (x)
{
    if (!this.contains(x))
    {
        this.items[x.toString()] = x;
        this.item_count++;
    }

    return this;
};

ObjectSet.prototype.remove = function (x)
{
    if (this.contains(x))
    {
        delete this.items[x.toString()];
        this.item_count--;
    }

    return this;
};

ObjectSet.prototype.clear = function ()
{
    this.items = {};
    this.item_count = 0;

    return this;
};

ObjectSet.prototype.isEmpty = function ()
{
    return this.item_count === 0;
};

ObjectSet.prototype.count = function ()
{
    return this.item_count;
};

ObjectSet.prototype.values = function ()
{
    var i, ret = [];

    for (i in this.items)
    {
        if (this.items.hasOwnProperty(i))
            ret.push(this.items[i]);
    }

    return ret;
};
```

Answer (score 10):

I used Map, solved my case

```
const objectsMap = new Map();
const placesName = [
  { place: "here", name: "stuff" },
  { place: "there", name: "morestuff" },
  { place: "there", name: "morestuff" },
];
placesName.forEach((object) => {
  objectsMap.set(object.place, object);
});
console.log(objectsMap);
```

Answer (score 9):

It's not possible for all objects, but if your object has a `.toString()` method implemented, it is:

```
var x = {toString: function(){ return 'foo'; }};
var y = {toString: function(){ return 'bar'; }};
var obj = {};
obj[x] = 'X';
obj[y] = 'Y';
console.log(obj);
// { foo: 'X', bar: 'Y' }
```

If you want to make this easier, make it a class:

```
function myObj(name){
   this.name = name;
}
myObj.prototype.toString = function(){ return this.name; }

var obj = {};
obj[new myObj('foo')] = 'X';
obj[new myObj('bar')] = 'Y';
```

Comment: All objects have a *toString* method inherited from *Object.prototype*. Assigning the object to a property name will call its *toString* method anyway, so no need to do so explicitly. You can't guarantee that an object's *toString* will be unique for all objects, so Sophistifunk's approach is better (i.e. store objects in an array and provide a wrapper with methods to add, retrieve and remove members).

Comment: @RobG - You're missing the point.  The `toString()` methods I added were so that you could return a unique hash of the current object.  In this case, I'm just returning `'foo'` and `'bar'`, but you could easily hash anything else that identifies the object (hence the `prototype` example).  As for your first statement, no... Assigning `toString()` as a property will call that function, NOT the one it inherits from `Object.prototype`

Comment: For all I care, `var guid=0; myObj.prototype.toString = function(){ return (this.guid || (this.guid=guid++)); }` would work.

Comment: @cwolves - all stored objects will need to have unique names, so better to automate it and keep it private.

Comment: @RobG - if all the objects are the same type, doing it like this is better (see my last guid comment if you wish) as it's O(1) lookups unlike Array.indexOf

Comment: @RobG - First, I don't agree with the idea that every programming concept should be transfered from one language to another.  I think this is an example where JS just does things differently.  However, if a Set class is to be used, it should still use a hash, NOT an array like Sophistifunk's example.  Set `obj.__index=guid` or something and hash off of that.

Comment: What happens if you can't override the toString function for all the objects that might ever be inserted into the set? Also, I must be able to insert js objects which are clones of each other. I am surprised that the author has accepted this rather naive answer...

Comment: I tried this and adding a `toString` method didn't prevent duplicate objects being added to the set.

Answer (score 4):

For what you're trying to do (sets of objects), there is no native Javascript implementation. You would have to implement this on your own. One way to do this would be to implement a hashing function for your objects. The backing data-type of the set would be an associative array, where the key of the array is the value you get from calling the object's hash function, and the value of the array is the object itself.

Of course, this doesn't address the issue that you highlighted, so you will need to take equality into account as well (implement an equals function perhaps)?

Instead of making the hash function a property of the object itself, you can have a standalone hash function that takes in an object as input and generates a hash value (presumably by iterating over its properties).

Using this method you should be able to get `O(1)` for insertion, searching, and removing (not counting the order of the hash function, which shouldn't be any worse than `O(n)`, especially if you are iterating over its properties to create your hashed value).

Answer (score 4):

**ECMAScript6 `Set`** should behave like that:

- Standard: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-set-o-p-v-throw
- Unofficial ES6 cheat sheet: https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#map--set--weakmap--weakset

Working example on Firefox 32 (but not implemented in Chromium 37):

```
if (Set) {
  var s = new Set()
  var a = {}
  var b = {}
  var c = {}
  s.add(a)
  s.add(b)
  s.add(b)
  assert(s.size === 2)
  assert(s.has(a))
  assert(s.has(b))
  assert(!s.has(c))
}
```

This is not surprising since `{} != {}`: equality compares object addresses by default.

A module that implements it for browsers without support: https://github.com/medikoo/es6-set

Answer (score 2):

Javascript Set's don't do deep object comparison.

Using lodash, this is a unique array with deep object comparison:

```
const objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];
 
_.uniqWith(objects, _.isEqual);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given an array of the following type:

```ts
Array<{ foo: T1, bar: T2 }>
```

You can build a corresponding dictionary of type:

```ts
{ [foo: T1]: Set<T2> }
```

The look-up for `{ foo: fooValue, bar: barValue }` can be performed as follows:

```ts
if (fooValue in dictionary && dictionary[fooValue].has(barValue))
```

This way we can build what would be an `ObjectSet<T1, T2>`
.
If you now have three elements, you can build the following dictionary:

```ts
{ [foo: T1]: ObjectSet<T2, T3> }
```

and extend your ObjectSet to any number of properties by induction.

That is assuming your types can be used as index signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Just typed this up, it's only briefly tested:

```
var Set = function Set()
{
    var list = [];

    var contains;
    this.contains = contains = function(x) {
        return list.indexOf(x) >= 0;
    }

    var put;
    this.put = put = function(x) {
        if (!contains(x))
            list.push(x);

        return this;
    }

    var remove;
    this.remove = remove = function(x)
    {
        var idx = list.indexOf(x);
        if (idx >= 0)
            list.splice(idx,1);

        return this;
    }

    var all;
    this.all = all = function()
    {
        return list.concat();
    }

    return this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I believe `indexOf` runs in O(n) time.  In the question, I stated I needed better efficiency than that.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of the post :-/ It's pretty much a custom hash function then.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the inner call of function works when prefixed with *this*. 
Exemple:

```
var put;
this.put = put = function(x) {
    if (!this.contains(x))
        list.push(x);

    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, there is no native ecmascript class like std::set, where you pass an comparator function. You can implement this data structure, of course, as in any other programming language. But for most use cases i suggest something easier:

- If your objects have some kind of key or id field, and you want O(1) operations for operations like find/add/update/delete, you should use a map using this id field.
- If you don't have a key, just want avoid duplications in a collection, you can use map or even set, using `JSON.stringify(o, Object.keys(o).sort())` as an id. If you have nested objects or arrays, you should short its items either (i didn't wrote that part).

I wrote a class that can match both:

```
class ObjectSet {
    constructor(iterable) {
        this.map = new Map()
        if(!iterable) {
            return;
        }
        for(o of iterable) {
            this.map.set(this._getId(o), o);
        }
    }

    _getId(o) {
        return o.id ? o.id :
            JSON.stringify(o, Object.keys(o).sort());
    }

    get(id) {
        return this.map.get(id);
    }

    has(o) {
        return this.map.has(this._getId(o));
    }

    //add or update. Call "add" if you want to match ES6 Set interface
    set(o) {
        this.map.set(this._getId(o), o);
    }

    delete(o) {
        this.map.delete(this._getId(o));
    }

    values() {
        return this.map.values();
    }

    [Symbol.iterator] () {
        return this.values();
    }

    get size() {
        return this.map.size;
    }
}

//first use case example, fast find and update:
let objSet = new ObjectSet();

//add
objSet.set({
    id: 1,
    name: "John",
    age: 30
});
const eric = {
    id: 2,
    name: "Eric",
    age: 27
}
//add
objSet.set(eric)
console.log(objSet.size); //2

//update object of id 2
objSet.set({
    id: 2,
    name: "Eric",
    age: 28
})
console.log(objSet.size); // still 2


for(o of objSet) {
    console.log(o);
}
/*
prints:

{ id: 1, name: 'John Abbot', age: 30 }
{ id: 2, name: 'Eric', age: 28 }
*/

objSet.delete({id: 1});//deletes john
objSet.delete(eric);
console.log(objSet.size);//0


//second use case, lets remove duplicated objects using this class
let points = [
    {
        x: 10,
        y: 40
    },
    {
        x: 10,
        y: 40
    },
    {
        x: 10,
        y: 35
    }
]


//lets remove duplicated objects using ObjectSet:
objSet = new ObjectSet(points);
console.log(o.size);//2
for(o of objSet) {
    console.log(o);
}

//same with set method
objSet.set({
    x: 10,
    y: 35
});
console.log(objSet.size);//still 2
```

Answer (score -2):

Please use this code as a reference.

```js
const fruits = [
  {name: 'apple', price: 100},
  {name: 'apple', price: 100},
  {name: 'orange', price: 200},
  {name: 'grapes', price: 300}
];

const hasFruitDuplicated = () => {
  const duplicatedDeleteFruits = fruits.filter((fruit, index) =>
    fruits.findIndex(item => item.name === fruit.name && item.price === fruit.price) === index
  );
  return duplicatedDeleteFruits;
};
```