# Remove duplicate from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I want to remove each  copy of  object from array:

```js
  const object = [
    { label: "SUA", value: "sua" },
    { label: "SUA", value: "sua" },
    { label: "Florida", value: "florida" }
  ];
  console.log(object.map(i=> [...new Set(i)]))
```

At the end i have to get like:

```js
const object = [
    { label: "Florida", value: "florida" }
  ];
```

How to do this in my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set of objects in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657219/set-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Do you mean you want an array with unique objects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: What happened to SUA? Why is it removed entirely?

Comment: It's really not so clear what you are asking. Are you sure the end result shouldn't be: `[{ label: "SUA", value: "sua" }, { label: "Florida", value: "florida" }] instead of just the florida object?

Comment: You need to have better test cases and problem is not clear what you are trying to solve.

[
    { label: "SUA2", value: "sua2" },
    { label: "SUA", value: "sua" },
    { label: "Florida", value: "florida" },
{ label: "SUA", value: "sua" },
  ]

what is your expected result?

Comment: @Phil I think because there was two of it, and all of them got removed

Comment: @UKS I don't think so. Appearently, the OP wants to remove all occurrences of duplicates...

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 for loops to achieve your functionality.

```
let result = [];
for(let i=0;i<object.length ;i++) {
    let isDuplicate = false;
    for(let j=0; j<object.length;j++) {
        if(object[i].label === object[j].label && object[i].value === object[j].value && i !== j) {
            isDuplicate = true;   
        }
    }
    if(!isDuplicate) result.push(object[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how many copies of each element you'd like to keep in the array, create a Map by definition `Map<Location, number>` and tabulate the number of occurrences of each `Location` object. Afterwards, take each element and append it to an array only once.

```js
type Location = {label: string, value: string};

const object: Location[] = [
    { label: "SUA", value: "sua" },
    { label: "SUA", value: "sua" },
    { label: "Florida", value: "florida" }
];
const objects: Map<Location, number> = new Map();

for (const location of object)
    if (objects.has(location))
        objects.set(location, objects.get(location) + 1);
    else
        objects.set(location, 1);

const filtered: Location[] = [];

for (const location of objects)
    if (location[1] === 1) // You change 1 to any value depending on how many copies of each you'd like.
        filtered.push(location[0];
```

> **Note** This is TypeScript for clarity, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Short way:

```js
const object = [
  { label: "SUA", value: "sua" },
  { label: "SUA", value: "sua" },
  { label: "Florida", value: "florida" }
];

const a = object.filter((v, i, a) => a.findIndex(t => (t.label === 
v.label && t.value === v.value)) === i);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: it would fail on 

object = [
  { label: "SUA", value: "sua" },
  { label: "SUA", value: "sua" },
  { label: "Florida", value: "florida" },
{ label: "SUA", value: "sua" },
];

a = object.filter((v, i, a) => a.findIndex(t => (t.label === 
v.label && t.value === v.value)) === i);

Comment: No, you wrong it not fail, you can check it before you wrote a comment @Tom

Comment: it's wrong because he wanted to remove all the duplicated objs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 set -

```
const unique = [...new Set(object.map(({value}) => value))].map(e => object.find(({value}) => value == e));

console.log("unique",unique);

//[{label: "SUA", value: "sua"},{label: "Florida", value: "florida"}]
```

for your problem you can simply use reduce -

```
const uniq =  object.reduce((a,b)=>{return a.value === b.value ? {} :[b]},[])

console.log(uniq);

//[{label: "Florida", value: "florida"}]
```

Comment: object = [
    { label: "SUA2", value: "sua2" },
    { label: "SUA", value: "sua" },
    { label: "Florida", value: "florida" },
{ label: "SUA", value: "sua" },
  ];

uniq =  object.reduce((a,b)=>{return a.value === b.value ? {} :[b]},[])

//  {label: "SUA", value: "sua"} ????

how would this work??

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution with lodash

```
const object = [
    { label: "SUA", value: "sua" },
    { label: "SUA", value: "sua" },
    { label: "Florida", value: "florida" }
  ];

result = _.xor(_.uniqWith(object,_.isEqual),object)
```