# Find value of an object

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

I have an object acting like Hash table.

```
var ob = {
  "Earnings": {
    "name": "Finance",
    "id": "0"
  },

  "Total": {
    "token_id": 90,
    "Token": {
      "name": "E32"
    }
  }
}
```

Now the point is that I have **value** not key of ob.

I have value :

```
{
  "token_id": 90,
  "Token": {
    "name": "E32"
  }
}
}
```

I need to find whether the **value exists in ob** efficiently. I had tried the loop approach like this.

```
for (var key in ob) {
  if (ob.HasOwnProperty(key)) {
    //check for the value
  }
}
```

This approach is fine for small data but for large data its taking time.
So, Is there any way I can solve this use case by getting(searching) in O(1) time?

Comment: What is the expected result? What is current benchmark?

Comment: I am getting the expected result but is there any way to do without the loop?

Answer (score 1):

All I can think is to the convert the value in the json as a Set object

[JavaScript implementation of a set data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523436/javascript-implementation-of-a-set-data-structure)

when you query the set it will be `O(1)` amortized when you convert it to a set it will be `O(n)`.

or you can swap the value and key and put in a HashMap which some people implement for javascript.